# Why is predicate pushdown not working?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, predicate, apache-spark-sql

## Programm Sketch

- I create a HiveContext `hiveContext`.
- With that context, I create a DataFrame `df` from a JDBC relational table.
- I register the DataFrame `df` via `df.registerTempTable("TESTTABLE")`.
- I start a HiveThriftServer2 via 
  `HiveThriftServer2.startWithContext(hiveContext)`.

The TESTTABLE contains 1,000,000 entries, columns are ID (INT) and NAME (VARCHAR)

```
+-----+--------+
| ID  |  NAME  |
+-----+--------+
| 1   | Hello  |
| 2   | Hello  |
| 3   | Hello  |
| ... | ...    |
```

With Beeline I access the SQL Endpoint (at port 10000) of the HiveThriftServer and perform a query. E.g.

```
SELECT * FROM TESTTABLE WHERE ID='3'
```

When I inspect the QueryLog of the DB with the SQL Statements executed I see

```
/*SQL #:1000000 t:657*/  SELECT \"ID\",\"NAME\" FROM test;
```

So there happens no predicate pushdown , as the where clause is missing.

## Questions

This gives raise to the following questions:

- Why is no predicate pushdown performed?
- Can this be changed by not using registerTempTable?
- If so, how? Or is this a known restriction of the HiveThriftServer?

## Counterexample

If I create a DataFrame `df` in Spark SQLContext and call

```
df.filter( df("ID") === 3).show()
```

I observe

```
/*SQL #:1*/SELECT \"ID\",\"NAME\" FROM test WHERE ID = 3;
```

as expected.

Comment: Did you try to execute the explain plan on your DataFrame filter? df.filter(...).explain(true)

Comment: Ohh, good hint. Will try that out!!!

Comment: So what did the explain plan give you?

Comment: @eliasah: Unfortunately, I see no way, where to place the `explain` command for the case  Query -> ThriftServer -> HiveContext -> Query execution, as I can not programmatically control what the ThriftServer does or where to hook in.

Comment: You place it on the Dataframe, e.g let's consider a certain number of transformations that leads to a results in a DataFrame df. The command df.explain(true) will give you the query plan, physical plan and the logical plan of your built query.

Comment: @eliasah: For the latter case `df.filter(...)` I can call `df.filter(...).explain(true)`, but not for the first case where I have no programmatic control. The internal control flow (I suppose) is: SQL Query (via Beeline) -> ThriftServer -> .... -> Query Execution. The only thing I do is execute a query from Beeline. Having said, I have no DataFrame, on which to call `.explain(...)`.

Comment: Ok I see. I'm not sure if there is a similar procedure in hive thought. Sorry, I haven't dive into thirft and hive specifics yet. I wouldn't be able to help you on that first case

Comment: Still, many thanks for your help.

Comment: `EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM TESTTABLE WHERE ID='3'` should work although I doubt it will be useful. I tried Spark 1.5.1 in local mode with default settings combined with PostgreSQL 9.4 and simple predicates are pushed-down as expected.

Comment: @zero: Great, will try that out.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably too late to answer.
In this scenario, this did not work because ID is defined as Int and in the original query you are passing a string ('3'). Predicate pushdown looks for the same column name and the type as well.