# Elasticsearch-hadoop & Elasticsearch-spark sql - Tracing of statements scan&scroll

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, elasticsearch-hadoop

We are trying to integrate ES (1.7.2, 4 node cluster) with Spark (1.5.1, compiled with hive and hadoop with scala 2.11, 4 node cluster), there is hdfs coming into equation (hadoop 2.7,4 nodes) and thrift jdbc server and elasticsearch-hadoop-2.2.0-m1.jar

Thus, there are two ways of executing statement on ES.

1. Spark SQL with scala

   ```
   val conf = new  SparkConf().setAppName("QueryRemoteES").setMaster("spark://node1:37077").set("spark.executor.memory","2g")
   conf.set("spark.logConf", "true")
   conf.set("spark.cores.max","20")
   conf.set("es.index.auto.create", "false")
   conf.set("es.batch.size.bytes", "100mb")
   conf.set("es.batch.size.entries", "10000")
   conf.set("es.scroll.size", "10000")
   conf.set("es.nodes", "node2:39200")
   conf.set("es.nodes.discovery","true")
   conf.set("pushdown", "true")

   sc.addJar("executorLib/elasticsearch-hadoop-2.2.0-m1.jar")
   sc.addJar("executorLib/scala-library-2.10.1.jar")

   sqlContext.sql("CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE geoTab USING org.elasticsearch.spark.sql OPTIONS (resource 'geo_2/kafkain')" )

   val all: DataFrame = sqlContext.sql("SELECT count(*) FROM geoTab WHERE transmittersID='262021306841042'")
   .....
   ```
2. Thrift server (code executed on spark)

   ```
   ....
   polledDataSource = new ComboPooledDataSource()
   polledDataSource.setDriverClass("org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver")
   polledDataSource.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:hive2://node1:30001")
   polledDataSource.setMaxPoolSize(5)
   dbConnection = polledDataSource.getConnection
   dbStatement = dbConnection.createStatement

   val dbResult = dbStatement.execute("CREATE TEMPORARY EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS geoDataHive6(transmittersID STRING,lat DOUBLE,lon DOUBLE) STORED BY 'org.elasticsearch.hadoop.hive.EsStorageHandler' TBLPROPERTIES('es.resource' = 'geo_2/kafkain','es.query'='{\"query\":{\"term\":{\"transmittersID\":\"262021306841042\"}}}','es.nodes'='node2','es.port'='39200','es.nodes.discovery' = 'false','es.mapping.include' = 'trans*,point.*','es.mapping.names' = 'transmittersID:transmittersID,lat:point.lat,lon:point.lon','pushdown' = 'true')")

   dbStatement.setFetchSize(50000)
   dbResultSet = dbStatement.executeQuery("SELECT count(*) FROM geoDataHive6")
   .....
   ```

I have following issues and due to fact that they are connected, I have decided to pack them into one question on stack:

1. It seems that method using Spark SQL supports pushdown of what goes behind WHERE (whether es.query is specified or not), time of execution is the same and is acceptable. But solution number 1 definitely does not support pushdow of aggregating functions, i.e. presented count(*) is not executed on side of ES, but only after all data are retrieved - ES returns rows and Spark SQL counts them. Please confirm if this is correct behaviour
2. Solution number one behaves strange in that whether pushdown is passed true or false, time is equal
3. Solution number 2 seems to support no pushdown, it does not matter in what way I try to specify the sub-query, be it part of the table definition or in WHERE clause of the statement, it seems it is just fetching all the huge index and then to make the maths on it. Is it so that thrift-hive is not able to do pushdown on ES
4. I'd like to trace queries in elastic search, I do set following:

   ```
   //logging.yml
   index.search.slowlog: TRACE, index_search_slow_log_file
   index.indexing.slowlog: TRACE, index_indexing_slow_log_file

   additivity:
     index.search.slowlog: true
     index.indexing.slowlog: true
   ```

All index.search.slowlog.threshold.query,index.search.slowlog.threshold.fetch and even index.indexing.slowlog.threshold.index are set to 0ms.
And I do see in slowlog file common statements executed from sense (so it works). But I don't see Spark SQL or thrift statements executed against ES. I suppose these are scan&scroll statement because if i execute scan&scroll from sense, these are also not logged. Is it possible somehow to trace scan&scroll on side of ES?

Answer (score 2):

1. As far as I know it is an expected behavior. All sources I know behave exactly the same way and intuitively it make sense. SparkSQL is designed for analytical queries and it make more sense to fetch data, cache and process locally. See also [Does spark predicate pushdown work with JDBC?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32573991/1560062)
2. I don't think that `conf.set("pushdown", "true")` has any effect at all. If you want to configure connection specific settings it should be passed as an `OPTION` map as in the second case. Using `es` prefix should work as well
3. This is strange indeed. [Martin Senne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1211082/martin-senne) reported [a similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33462386/1560062) with PostgreSQL but I couldn't reproduce that.

Answer (score 2):

After a discussion I had with Costin Leau on the elasticsearch discussion group, he pointed out the following and I ought sharing it with you :

There are a number of issues with your setup:

1. You mention using Scala 2.11 but are using Scala 2.10. Note that if you want to pick your Scala version, `elasticsearch-spark` should be used, `elasticsearch-hadoop` provides binaries for Scala 2.10 only.
2. The pushdown functionality is only available through Spark DataSource. If you are not using this type of declaration, the `pushdown` is not passed to ES (that's how Spark works). Hence declaring `pushdown` there is irrelevant.
3. Notice that how all params in ES-Hadoop start with `es.` - the only exceptions are `pushdown` and `location` which are Spark DataSource specific (following Spark conventions as these are Spark specific features in a dedicated DS)
4. Using a temporary table does count as a DataSource however you need to use `pushdown` there. If you don't, it gets activated by default hence why you see no difference between your runs; you haven't changed any relevant param.
5. Count and other aggregations are not pushed down by Spark. There might be something in the future, according to the Databricks team, but there isn't anything currently. For count, you can do a quick call by using `dataFrame.rdd.esCount`. But it's an exceptional case.
6. I'm not sure whether Thrift server actually counts as a DataSource since it loads data from Hive. You can double check this by enabling logging on the `org.elasticsearch.hadoop.spark` package to DEBUG. You should see whether the SQL does get translated to the DSL.

I hope this helps!

Comment: I wasn't able to find anything about `elasticsearch-spark`. I thought `elasticsearch-hadoop` includes Spark support?

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: Is there a downloadable project called `elasticsearch-spark` like there is `elasticsearch-hadoop`? I didn't find any on github.

Comment: `elasticsearch-spark`: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/current/install.html#:~:text=pig%20artifact-,Apache%20Spark.,-%3Cdependency%3E%0A%20%20%3CgroupId%3Eorg